# Java RandomString Class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HangMan RandomString Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818297/hangman-randomstring-class)

Here are the directions:

Create a `RandomString` class and implement the following:

1. Create a file named guess_phrases.txt that contains phrases to be guessed in your Hangman game. This file will have one guess phrase per line.
2. A constructor that receives the name of a file to get string values from. The constructor should read in the phrases from the file and store them for later use.
3. A method that returns a random string value from the file; this value shouldn't be repeated until all guess phrases in the file have been used.

Create a main method to test that next is working correctly by repeatedly calling next & printing the result – you should not have any repeats, and the phrases should not be in the same order as in the file.

I created a file called *guess_phrases.txt* with random phrases. When I run this I get an error, also it is not printed randomly, why is this? How can I fix this ?

This is what I have in the RandomString Class

```
public class RandomString {

    Random random = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> guessPhrases = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner fileScan;

    public RandomString(String guessPhrases) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // create a Scanner object to read from the file
        fileScan = new Scanner(new File("guess_phrases.txt"));

        // add all of the phrases from the file into the ArrayList
        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {

            String line = guessPhrases.nextLine(); // get input
            System.out.println(line); // print line
            guessPhrases.add(line); // add line to array list
        }
    }

    public String next() {
        int i = random.nextInt(guessPhrases.size());
        return guessPhrases.get(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at RandomString.next(RandomString.java:32)
 at RandomString.main(RandomString.java:40)

Comment: You have to pass a positive value to random.nextInt(int). [Hava a look at the Doku here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

Comment: what is the output at System.out.println(line);

Answer (score 1):

Since this is obviously a homework question, I'll just give you a hint -- what happens in your code if the file is empty (doesn't have any phrases)?